# Android AlertDialog buttons unresponsive

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So I have this dialog box that pops up.

The buttons, however, are unresponsive. The debug lines inside of the onClick methods aren't being reached.

What am I doing wrong or not doing?

Here's my code, followed by my XML for the dialog box.

```
    lv = new ListView(this);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);
    lv.setId(getTaskId());
    setContentView(lv);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new  OnItemClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                long id) {
             TextView v=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.info);
             String str = (String) v.getText();
             String ssid = str.substring((str.indexOf(" ")+1), str.indexOf(newline));
             AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
             b.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.loginbox,(ViewGroup) view));
             b.setPositiveButton(R.id.loginbutton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      Log.i("Button","Log in");
                   }
               });
               b.setNegativeButton(R.id.cancelbutton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       Log.i("Button","Cancel");
                       dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });

             Log.i("Click",ssid);
        }       
        });
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/ssidlabel"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:text="@string/ssidlabel" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:text="@string/password" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:text="@string/login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username"
    android:text="@string/cancel" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         TextView v=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.info);
         String str = (String) v.getText();
         String ssid = str.substring((str.indexOf(" ")+1), str.indexOf(newline));
         AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
         b.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.loginbox, null, false));
         b.setPositiveButton(R.id.loginbutton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  Log.i("Button","Log in");
               }
           });
           b.setNegativeButton(R.id.cancelbutton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   Log.i("Button","Cancel");
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           });

         AlertDialog alertDialog = b.create();
         alertDialog.show();

         Log.i("Click",ssid);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I see what I did now. You and TronicZomB helped me see what I did wrong. I set the view when I inflated the xml, prior to adding the buttons (hence, lack of buttons), and when I tried to call .show() after that, it gave me errors due to how I inflated the view

Comment: .create is unnecessary. Calling show on a builder will create and sore the dialog in one line

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
lv = new ListView(this);
lv.setAdapter(aa);
lv.setId(getTaskId());
setContentView(lv);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new  OnItemClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
         TextView v=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.info);
         String str = (String) v.getText();
         String ssid = str.substring((str.indexOf(" ")+1), str.indexOf(newline));
         AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
         b.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.loginbox,(ViewGroup) view));
         b.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  Log.i("Button","Log in");
               }
           });
           b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   Log.i("Button","Cancel");
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           });

         b.show();
         Log.i("Click",ssid);
    }       
    });
```

And then you can delete your `<Button>`s from your xml. The `.setPositiveButton` and `.setNegativeButton` will create the buttons for you and there is no need to create them in the xml and reference them with `R.id`.

Comment: Does the `AlertDialog` even show up? Where are you calling the `.show()` on your `Builder` b?

Comment: Yes, the dialog shows up. I'm, not calling `.show()`, though. I think the term is to `inflate`

Comment: Call `.show()`. This will return the `AlertDialog` that is created with your `Builder` b. The buttons should appear then.

Comment: Just put `b.show();` right above your `Log.i("Click",ssid);`. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: That gave me errors `05-03 14:18:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(28086): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Comment: Try to inflate with a `null` `ViewGroup` in the `setView` method.

Comment: I did that, and it worked, but Michael said it first, so I awarded him

Comment: No I can't. I need 15 reputation for that. You could upvote and favorite my question and give me a bit more reputation, so I could upvote your answer, however :)

Comment: Favoriting doesn't ash rep but I did hocks for your efforts to learn.